# How to save captured image without compress

Tags: android

I want to capture image and save it to storage. For storing am using below code

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Feedback");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(root, Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME+".jpeg");
            checkFlowIdisPresent(file);



            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

            photo = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(photo, 300, 300);


            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

            try {
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            displayPic();


        }
    }
```

Now the problem is image quality is lost. So how to save an image without losing its quality.
if am using `photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);` to save image it doesn't losing its quality but the problem is i wanted to resize the image 300*300.
Please help me out.

Comment: extractThumbnail doesn't scale, it cropps

Comment: also try to use: Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG for better quality

Comment: cropping is ok for me... Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG it doesn't helped

Comment: so how to resolve this problem???

Comment: `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");` You do not have to extract a thumbnail from that as it is already a thumbnail. The original picture you have to get at another way.

Answer (score 0):

User same code for capturing the photo. like -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
selectedImageUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
                  MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedImageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
// - selectedImageUri is global variable
```

now onActivityResult

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri );
```

after getting the result just resize your image using this method

```
public static bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    int width = 300; // - Dimension in pixels
    int height= 300;  // - Dimension in pixels
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false);
}
```

Comment: if i set photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);   then in onActivityResult this data.getExtras().get("data") will be null. how to get bitmap to call resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) method

Comment: i wanted to store image in internal storage but MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is for external storage . so i changed to MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI but problem is it thows an exception Writing to internal storage is not supported.

Comment: `i wanted to store image in internal storage`. It is unclear what you consider to be 'internal storage'.

Comment: `data.getExtras().get("data") will be null.` Use `data.getData()` to get the uri for the .jpeg file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any compression,then use direct bitmap what you are fetching from gallery for camera.Thanks

```
if(this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Feedback");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(root, Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME+".jpeg");
        checkFlowIdisPresent(file);
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
       // use this bitmap as it is
    }
```

Comment: Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality.

Comment: then it will return very bad quality image

Comment: captured with 13 megapixel camera

Comment: i throught that image was png but if you used jpeg then make it 100 and just remove "photo = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(photo, 300, 300)" this one then check

Comment: No still same problem even after removing photo = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(photo, 300, 300)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121235/discussion-between-venkatesh-gowda-and-saveen).

Comment: `// use this bitmap as it is`. Well that is a thumbnail already.

Comment: @greenapps sir bimap is same, there is no compression at all